# Web Scraping an Image

Tags: image, hyperlink, web-scraping

I was thinking about the applications of web scraping (still quite new to it) and came up with a question.  Can you get an image from a page if there are advertisements on the page (like can you avoid advertisements and only look for the correct image content on the page)?  Also, if the image is also a link to another page, can you say go to the next page and get that image (and then go from there until you either reach a certain amount or get all of the images)?  This would mean avoiding going to the advertisements pages.

Comment: You can use this chrome extension and customized your scraping agent conditionally as you want. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraping-app/gpolcofcjjiooogejfbaamdgmgfehgff

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. If you use a tool like kimonolabs.com this can be relatively easy. You click the data that you want on the page, so instead of getting all images including advertisements, Kimono uses the CSS selectors of the data you clicked to know which data to scrape.

You can use Kimono to scrape data within links as well. It's actually a very common use. Here's a break-down of that strategy: https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203438300-Source-URLs-to-crawl-from-another-kimono-API

This might be a helpful solution for you, especially if you're not a programmer because it doesn't require coding experience. It's a pretty powerful tool.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you are ok with PHP programming then give a look into php simple html dome parser. I have used it a lot and scrapped number of websites.